# apscheduler with mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, apscheduler

I'm trying to run this code:

```
from pytz import utc
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.mongodb import MongoDBJobStore

jobstores = {
  'default': MongoDBJobStore(database='apscheduler', collection='jobs', host='xxx', port=27017)
}
sched = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=1)
def job():
    print 'This job is run every second.'

sched.start()
```

but get error:
ValueError: This Job cannot be serialized since the reference to its callable () could not be determined. Consider giving a textual reference (module:function name) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i used decorator scheduled_job.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10185203)

Comment: @LawrenceAiello This *is* an answer (the OP solved their own problem). Just not a descriptive one.